# My firebase connection test fires connected and disconnected

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using the firebase connection [connection test](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html) detection script to show a modal if the user has disconnected but for some reason when the app loads it fires both cases and it shows the disconnected modal even though it has connection. What am I doing wrong.

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBAE_URL);
firebaseRef.child('.info/connected').on('value', function(connectedSnap) {
  if (connectedSnap.val() === true) {
    console.log("connected");
  } else {
    console.log("not connected");
    setTimeout(function(){
      $ionicPopup.show({
        title: 'Network is either down or poor wifi',
        template: 'Either pay for some wifi or go to a cafe',
        buttons: [{
          text: '<b>ok</b>',
          type: 'button-positive'
        }]
      });
    }, 8000)

  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you first create a Firebase client, it starts building a connection to the server. This can take some time. Until the connection is fully established, the client is not connected. To it fires `false` value in `.info/connected`.

Showing a modal dialog whenever the user loses their connection is probably a bad user experience. Network connections on mobile devices drop surprisingly regularly and Firebase shields the user from brief interruptions effortlessly. Showing a modal dialog is like screaming "YOU'RE OFFLINE, WE'RE ALL DOOMED, YOU HAVE NO INTERNET" in their face. Hardly a pleasant experience.

A more typical usage of `.info/connected` is to show a less obtrusive indicator, such as a little status icon. Alternatively you can show a modal if the user has been offline for a certain period.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to reply to your comment asking how to avoid the first false event, and I'm not sure if you still want an answer to this, but something simple like this should do the trick:

```
var wasPreviouslyConnected = false;
firebaseRef.child('.info/connected').on('value', function(connectedSnap) {
  if (connectedSnap.val() === true) {
    wasPreviouslyConnected = true;
    console.log("connected");
  }
  else if (wasPreviouslyConnected) {
    console.log("disconnected")
  }
  else {
    console.log("initial false connected snapshot while data is still loading");
  }
});
```